# Accessibility text for SwiftUI button action

Tags: ios, swiftui, accessibility, voiceover

I have a use case where I wanted to have different text for **VoiceOver** after SwiftUI button click.

Initial value is different and it can be set with **accessibilityLabel** or **accessibilityValue** for e.g. "Tap here to increment the count"

```
Button {
  // button action
} label: { 
  Text("Increment") 
} 
.accessibilityValue("Tap here to increment the count")
```

but how can I set a new value with button action, voice over should be calling count for e.g. "Count is 10"

can someone please suggest, which property should I use here

**Note*** *after button click I need only action text voice out and it should be without the initial text*

Comment: Did you manage this ? If so, how ?

Answer (score -1):

To change the `VoiceOver` text after a `SwiftUI` button click, you can use a state variable to dynamically update the `accessibilityLabel` of the button.

When the button is tapped, you can update this state variable, which in turn will update the accessibility text read by `VoiceOver`.

Here's a basic example to demonstrate this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var count = 0
    @State private var voiceOverText = "Tap here to increment the count"

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            count += 1
            voiceOverText = "Count is \(count)"
        }) {
            Text("Increment")
        }
        .accessibilityLabel(Text(voiceOverText))
    }
}
```